# How to pipe npm install progress bar to the terminal in go?

Tags: go, npm, pipe, command-line-interface

I have tried using **stdoutpipe and stderrpipe** like shown below.

```
shell := exec.Command("npm", args...)
shell.Dir = cwd

outpipe, _ := shell.StdoutPipe()
errpipe, _ := shell.StderrPipe()

shell.Start()

go func(pipe io.ReadCloser) {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(pipe)
    line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')

    for err == nil {
        fmt.Println(string(line))
        line, err = reader.ReadString('\n')
    }

    fmt.Println("exited")

}(outpipe)

go func(pipe io.ReadCloser) {

    reader := bufio.NewReader(pipe)
    line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')

    for err == nil {
        fmt.Println(string(line))
        line, err = reader.ReadString('\n')
    }

    fmt.Println("exited")

}(errpipe)

err := shell.Wait()

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

**However I only get output:**

```
added 87 packages, and audited 88 packages in 3s



9 packages are looking for funding

run `npm fund` for details



found 0 vulnerabilities
```

How do I get the installation progress bar that you get when you run npm install from the console?

I have also tried using a solution like below and printing the buffer after running shell.run() but it also gives the same output as the one above.

```
shell := exec.Command(command, args...)
shell.Dir = cwd
var stderr, stdout bytes.Buffer

shell.Stderr = &stderr
shell.Stdout = &stdout

return shell, &stdout, &stderr
```

Comment: The progress bar is likely only shown when attached to a TTY. It *might* work if you directly set the cmd's in & out to your process's `os.Stdin` and `os.Stdout`. Also just want to point out that naming your command value `shell` might be confusing later on since it is not a shell, and the most common issues with `exec` come from thinking that it works like a shell.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian your suggested solution did the trick :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved thanks [@Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7426/adrian)'s comment

```
cmd := exec.Command("npm", args...)
cmd.Dir = cwd

cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
```

Redirecting to **os's stdout and stderr** is what did the trick.